# Can I use mime/multipart reader for data read from a Conn?

Tags: networking, go

I am sending a BOUNDARY delimited JSON data through a TCP socket. I read that golang has a mime/multipart readers and I tried to utilize it, to no avail.

The code in question is:

```
//I create a reader wrapped around a Conn type with boundary previously defined
reader := multipart.NewReader(conn, MESSAGE_BOUNDARY)

//Then I have a gopher which reads the parts/data from it:
part, _ := reader.NextPart()
var line []byte
part.Read(line)
```

The issue is, NextPart() blocks and it's never passed. I never get a PART, even though I am receiving data (tried reading from the Conn before trying to get the next part and so on). I tried changing the multipart reader with a bufio reader, and with ReadString I got a what I was suppose to. Problem is, I can't use a single byte to delimit, since I'm passing large messages that might contain all kinds of bytes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show working example in the playground.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your data matches the format expected by the `mime/multipart Reader`.  In your case `reader.NextPart()` may be blocked waiting for a proper boundary or per-part headers.

See the example under [NewReader](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#NewReader) for reference:

```
--MESSAGE_BOUNDARY\r\n
Header1: Value\r\n
Header2: Value\r\n
\r\n
<part data>\r\n
--MESSAGE_BOUNDARY\r\n
Header1: Value\r\n
\r\n
<part data>\r\n
--MESSAGE_BOUNDARY--\r\n
```

Also, make sure to check the error value returned from `NextPart()`, it will tell you if there is a MIME encoding problem or a generic I/O error.

Lastly, the `part.Read(line)` will not work as written above, since your `line` buffer has a 0-byte capacity.  If it is OK to buffer each part in memory, then use [io/ioutil ReadAll](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) as in the `NewReader` example.  Otherwise, declare `line` as `line := make([]byte, 4096)` and use a loop to read out the part data in 4KB chunks.